# Do I need a new collection for each component with variables and tokens in Figma?

Tags: guidelines

I understand there are primitives, which are raw data, and I have to reference them. But do I have to create a new collection every time for each component? And how do modes blend into it then?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, here's some information that might help you:

- Primitives collection should be used as references in semantic tokens. Apart from that it is common practice to descope/unpublish primitives collection to make sure you and your team members won't be choosing wrong properties for components. [More information on how to unpublish variables in collection could be found here](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039238193-Hide-styles-components-and-variables-when-publishing).
- You can store different tokens inside one single collection and by specifying different names for variables (e.g. text / primary; text / secondary for different text variables) these tokens will be organized automatically according to the given name. [More information regarding token's naming convention here](https://uxdesign.cc/naming-design-tokens-347f630ba4f9).
- Keep in mind that Figma offers variable modes which allows you to assign multiple values for one single token. It comes in handy if you're designing light/dark modes for the application. [More information here](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/15343816063383-Modes-for-variables).

If something's not clear, I'll update my answer according to your comment.